# Detox and Android's "Open with" menu

Tags: android, detox

When using Detox to test universal links on an Android emulator (e.g. `https://app.mydomain.com/login`), the default behavior seems to be to bring up an "Open with" system menu. Is there an elegant way of working around this? Is this something that Android Test Butler supports? (it wasn't clear from a quick look at their documentation)

It looks like every run of Detox re-installs the app, so settings are lost between test runs. I tried to manually choose "always" open in my app and then re-run the tests, but the setting was immediately lost.

[image]

Comment: did you resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I use for this is to explicitly make the app the default via adb before running the tests.

API level <= 30:

```
adb shell pm set-app-link com.your.package.name always
```

API level >= 31:

```
adb shell pm set-app-links --package com.your.package.name 1 app.mydomain.com
```

You can run this from your node tests via `exec`/`execSync`.